# Can Util class can be abstract or final?

Tags: java

```
public final class DateUtil{

    public static void t1();

}

public abstract class DateUtil{

    public static void t1();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`abstract` classes are meant to be sub-classed, and their sub-classes are meant to be instantiated, so they are not a good fit for utility classes.

If you are asking about a class that contains only static utility methods and shouldn't be instantiated, make it `final` and make the constructor `private`. That's what the JDK developers did with classes such as `java.lang.Math`.

Comment: We make the constructor private, it means no other class can extend this class(make it final-not required)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Either or neither.

General opinion is that it should not be subclassable or instantiable, so add a `private` constructor. (Some people disagree.)

```
private DateUtil() {
    throw new Error();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, all Util classes are final and static. It will have private constructor.

So that anyone who is calling the method ,no need to create object and can directly access with class name.